# Visual Studio 2010 projects are never up to date

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects

I've hit an issue with some of the projects in our Visual Studio 2010 solution. When I build they are never up to date and always rebuild.

Using this post

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/21/enable-c-project-system-logging.aspx

I was able to figure out that some of my projects had headers listed which no longer existed. Removing these references fixed 5 of the projects.

But that leaves 13 which are always being built. The reason I get from the VS2010 log is

> devenv.exe Information: 0 : Project 'C:\path\to\project.vcxproj' up to date check disabled because the LastBuildState and/or LastBuildUnsuccessful properties are not set.

When I search google I'm getting hits for this message. But no solutions.

Does anyone know whats going on?

All these projects are NMake based. Kinda suspect that may be the root cause. Do NMake projects set these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969138/visual-studio-project-out-of-date/21759835)

I had to delete all .tlog files from my output.