# Visual Studio 2015: Program out of date

Tags: visual-studio

I've been using VS2015 RC until July 19th, then uninstalled and subsequently installed VS2015 Community (the official release). I was able to successfully debug and run C++ programs on VS2015 RC, but however, when I now try to run any simple program that I have successfully debugged in the past or any new one, VS2015 Community gives me a popup that says: "This project is out of date. ProjectName - Debug Win32. Would you like to build it?"

I've been on SO and found this: [Visual Studio Project out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969138/visual-studio-project-out-of-date), but even after deleting all the .tlog files, I've still been getting the same issue. I've also deleted all the .pdbs, but that hasn't helped either. Does anyone know what a fix might be? Thanks!

Comment: this fixed it for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/12954908/6720987

Answer (score 14):

You can change the build output verbosity setting to make Visual Studio 2015 tell you why it is rebuilding:

1. Build the solution
2. Change MSBuild project build output verbosity setting to **Detailed** or Diagnostics. It's found here:

   - Tools (menu)
   - Options
   - Project and Solution
   - Build and Run
3. Build the solution and check the Output view.

In my case it printed a message like this:

```
1>------ Up-To-Date check: Project: xyz, Configuration: xyz ------
1>Project not up to date because build input 'C:\ws\Missing.h' is missing.
```

... and removing that header from the project fixed the problem.

Comment: This worked for me. Somehow I had a file that was referenced in the project, but it was missing on disk. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are reading this then probably a Full Rebuild didn't help.

Most likely you have a reference to a **header file** in your project that **does not exist** on the filesystem.

Try opening every header file that your project refers to, and remove the ones that can't be opened.

Comment: Opening every header file can be almost impossible if you have a  huge project with hundreds of source and header files. The build output verbosity tip from CrouZ is pretty quick and painless

Comment: Yes, the build diagnostics will tell you that a header is missing.  The problem is that it only tells you the FIRST missing header.  If there are multiple headers missing, you'll have to re-do the build, with the diagnostics, for each missing header.  So, if you do have a huge project with hundreds of sources and headers, it's likely you'll have multiple missing files, in which case you need to do what this answer suggests anyway.