# "Project out of date" in VS community 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I recently changed from Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 (which worked fine) to the 2017 version, and at first, it was working fine. I save my projects in C:/_Dev/C++/My projects/. However, after using 2017 for less than 3 hours, I now get this message whenever I try to run a project:

"This project is out of date:
[insert file name]-Debug Win32"

Then I have the option to build it or not, and building does still work, but I don't like that something is going slightly wrong.

Note that since I got this error, I went back to my first C++ program to see if it now displays the message too, which it does. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    system("pause");
}
```

...So I'm fairly confident it's not my code causing the issue. It's been a couple of days since I started getting the error, and I've tried re-installing VSC 2017, deleting the *tlog files, cleaning, and rebuilding the project. I have not moved the project to a new file directory since its creation.

Does anyone know if this will turn into a big problem, or is it just something I have to put up with? If anyone knows more, I'd appreciate the advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Project out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969138/visual-studio-project-out-of-date)

Comment: `void main()` is not legal `C++`, it should be `int main()`.

Comment: Didn't know that it wasn't legal, thanks for the tip :) I did change it to int later, and it didn't solve the problem.