# What does the MSBuild -> (arrow/dash greater/-&gt;) operator do?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

What does the `->` (or `-&gt;`) operator do inside MSBuild?

Some example code from another question: [File Tracker Log file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729519/file-tracker-log-file-format)

```
<!-- Appended tlog to track custom build events -->
<WriteLinesToFile
  File="$(IntDir)$(ProjectName).write.1.tlog"
  Lines="@(CustomBuildStep-&gt;'^%(Identity)');@(CustomBuildStep-&gt;MetaData('Outputs')-&gt;FullPath()-&gt;Distinct())"/>
```

**Bonus question**: What does `@(CustomBuildStep-&gt;'^%(Identity)')` do in the above code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `->` operator in MSBuild is the [transformation operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_Transforming). It transforms an item list into a new item list by substituting the string on the right-hand side using metadata of the original items.

The `->'^%(Identity)'` magic is partially described in the [task batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171474.aspx) documentation. The `Identity` metadata is just the value itself, so that transformation just prepends "^". It also causes batching because of the `%` sigil, so the whole `WriteLinesToFile` task gets executed for each `CustomBuildStep` item.

Comment: note that `->` is *also* used for item functions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886422.aspx