# Microsoft Tracker.exe documentation required

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild

I'd like to use Tracker.exe for incremental building a custom step in Visual Studio 2015.

Does anyone have the full doc on how to do it? The help supplied in "Tracker.exe /?" is not elaborate enough.

Comment: Don't have VS2015 here, but did they really rename tracker.exe to filetracker.exe? That's confusing.. If you search around for tracker.exe you'll find more info.

Comment: see e.g. [How does Visual Studio know my project is up to date so it can skip running MSBuild?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107313/how-does-visual-studio-know-my-project-is-up-to-date-so-it-can-skip-running-msbu) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729519/file-tracker-log-file-format. In short: haven't seen full documentation of it anywhere (yet), but from looking at how it's used by msbuild it's not too hard to figure out what to do with it

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Tracker"! Corrected.

Comment: Could not find full documentation about it. Did you want to track file for incremental building in Visual studio 2015? if yes, you can write task to implement it based on .NET API:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.filetracker.aspx. and here is detail scripts for this feature:https://gist.github.com/xoofx/4539007